# Selenium C# RemoteWebDriver not finding XPath Elements

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver, invalidoperationexception

I'm using Selenium 2.25.1 API, and I'm trying to be able to find the elements using RemoteWebDriver(). Except when I try, it just fails to find the element. I've tried several different combinations with no luck and have been looking this up for a few days now.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement WaitForPage = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.XPath((String)data));
});
```

Is my code where it fails. Basically the data variable is an object grabbed from my database. I converted it, and going though the code it comes out perfectly fine. How the difference is, when I used just the browser (i.e. firefox, IE) it works just fine with no errors. But when I use it with RemoteWebDriver(), it throws InvalidOperationException and throws a popup saying it was unable to find the element. (Server did not provide any stacktrace information).

This is usually what I use

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), IEcapa);
```

When that is used, it just fails everytime.

Any ideas? I am completely puzzled. Anything is welcome and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using an implicit wait instead of an WebDriverWait statement.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement WaitForPage = driver.FindElement(By.XPath((String)data));
```

And make sure that the xpath you are getting from the data variable is valid. If possible post an some xpath you get from the database.

Comment: I made the changes you said to ImplicitlyWait, and it does time out longer than normal. Thank you! for that bit of info. 

An XPath that returns with the error is "//input[@tabindex="13"]". Then just goes on saying there was no stack trace info. It only does this with block of code.

    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer());


Using it with firefox works just fine though.

Comment: It seems like Selenium's jar file (I'm running the jar file in my command prompt) will open internet explorer, but it doesnt take any other conditions in InternetExplorerOptions(). Even more than that, it doesn't seem like it even recognize Internet explorer for any reason. I just tried using JQuery in it, and it threw an error, basically saying that the driver doesnt exist. So I'm like completely stumped...

Comment: Is it only an issue when using `DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer`? As in, if you use `DesiredCapabilities.Firefox` does this make any difference?

Comment: It makes a big difference. Using    DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer 
fails to locate any elements. However, using    DesiredCapabilities.FireFox
will locate all the elements without any scripting changes.

Comment: I can use JQuery to find the elements with IE and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well here is the problem... When I look at the driver when in debug mode, it says the "PageSource threw an exception". This is only by using DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer() when using RemoteWebDriver().

Comment: I fixed the issue. I You can use DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer() and have the standalone server running (The jar file) in order for it to work. Although I'm not sure why my problem got fixed, all I had to do though was restart my computer.